# How to fix Pusher Trigger when NOT SENDING and is ONLY RECEIVING : CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, pusher

I am setting up a real time notification using Pusher. I already got it working in my Test environment on cloud9 IDE. Eventually, when uploading  the Pusher Notification,on LIVE FTP, it's not working. I tried triggering an event in my IDE locally and the Notification was also received in my LIVE system.

I don't know if I left out a file to upload or I configured something wrong, or if it is server issue.

This is the existing codes: 
**--header.ctp**

```
<!--REAL TIME NOTIF REQUIREMENT-->
<script src="https://js.pusher.com/4.4/pusher.min.js"></script>

<script>
var pusher = new Pusher('xxxxxxxx', {
  cluster: 'ap1',
  forceTLS: true
});

var role='<?php echo $userRole; ?>';

var channel = pusher.subscribe('quotestat');
channel.bind('updated', function(data) {
    if(role=='customer_service_head' ) {
            // ADD VALIDATION HERE
            shownotif();
        } else if(role=='proprietor') {
            shownotif();
        }
    }

    function shownotif() {
        $.niftyNoty({
            type: 'dark',
            title: data['name'],
            message: data['message'],
            container: 'floating',
            // timer: 5000 //UNCOMMENT THIS IF YOU WANT THE NOTIF TO DISMISS AFTER 5 SECONDS
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

**--AppController.php**

```
require_once(ROOT . DS . 'app' . DS .'Vendor' . DS  . 'autoload.php');

class AppController extends Controller {
     public function livenotif($datalive) {
        echo '<br/>EXECUTING...';
    $options = array(
    'cluster' => 'ap1',
    'useTLS' => true
    );
    $pusher = new Pusher\Pusher(
    'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'xxxxx',
    $options
    );
        $pusher->trigger('quotestat', 'updated', $datalive);
    }
}
```

**--HomeController.php**

```
$datalive['user_id']=$user_id;
$datalive['name']=ucwords(strtolower($name));
$datalive['message']=$message;
$this->livenotif($datalive);
```

Locally, this codes works. So I don't understand why it doesn't on LIVE.

Comment: Pusher provides a debug console that allows you to check whether their services are receiving the messages sent by your server. When your server triggers a message does it show up in the console? 
Is your FTP server behind any firewalls or proxies that would prevent the request from succeeding?

Comment: there isn't anything in my FTP to prevent it from  succeding